# Добавление параметра к option value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

Не могли бы подсказать скрипт, заменяющий все определённые названия доменных имен в HTML документе с определенным `id`?

Т.е., например, имеется на странице в разных местах `option value` вида

```
<option value="http://site.ru">текст</option>
```

а нужно, чтобы скрипт выводил такой вид:

```
<option value="http://mysite.ru?http://site.ru">текст</option>
```

Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: @gera43, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("option").each(function(){
  var string = jQuery(this).val();
  var regexp = "site.ru";
  var result = "mysite.ru?http://site.ru";
  string = string.replace(regexp, result);
  jQuery(this).val(string);
});
```

Вся страница:

```
var code= jQuery("body").html();
var regexp = "site.ru";
var result = "mysite.ru?http://site.ru";
code = code.replace(regexp, result);
jQuery("body").html(code);
```

Comment: nick777, спасибо большое, но не выходит, а не подскажите, как тогда сделать замену всех упоминаний на site.ru во всём html файле?

Comment: В коде была ошибка, сейчас поправил.